# Как правильно настроить routing?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

API возвращает 404 на мой GET-запрос:

Мой API:

```
class ProductSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    color = ColorSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Product
        fields = (
            'id',
            'title',
            'short_title',
            'get_absolute_url',
            'get_cart_thumbnail',
            'get_related_thumbnail',
            'part_number',
            'price',
            'color',
            'get_weight_in_g',
            'get_volume_in_m3',
            'stock_spb'
        )


@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class ProductInfo(APIView):
    @staticmethod
    def get(request):
        product = models.Product.objects.filter(slug=request.split('/'))
        s_product = CitySerializer(product, many=False)
        return Response(s_product.data)
```

Мой роутер:

```
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'product', rest.ProductInfo, 'product')

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

Идея в том, чтобы API принимал запросы вида:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/catalog/product/slug-of-a-product/
```

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Почему вы используете APIView, а не ViewSet? Может из-за этого роутер не может парвильно смапить url и view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С роутами все было правильно. Вот класс, который делает всё то, что я хотел.

```
@permission_classes((permissions.AllowAny,))
class ProductInfo(RetrieveModelMixin, viewsets.GenericViewSet):
    queryset = models.Product.objects.all()
    lookup_field = "slug"
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
```

Answer (score 1):

[Судя по коду](https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/3.3.3/rest_framework/routers.py#L224) (и немножко по [документации](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#how-hyperlinked-views-are-determined)) вы забыли lookup_field. Выложите сериализатор для верности, я попробую запустить

Comment: Верно, дело было в том числе и в `lookup_field`,  но моя главная ошибка в том, что мне следовало использовать ViewSet, как подсказал @Chikiro